# How can i use paramiko after it give me this error encode_point has been deprecated on EllipticCurvePublicNumbers

Tags: python-3.x

How can i use paramiko after it give me this error "paramiko\kex_ecdh_nist.py:39: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: encode_point has been deprecated on EllipticCurvePublicNumbers and will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.public_bytes to obtain both compressed and unco"

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable gathering_facts to get past the warning. For some reason Ansible was getting stuck gathering facts.
After disabling gathering facts, I still get this warning, but Ansible is able to continue execution.

yaml file 
gather_facts: no